# Vectorized LU decomposition solve for multiple b

Tags: numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray

I'm preprocessing a quadratic matrix `A` of shape `(n,n)` with scipy's LU decomposition and then solve over and over again for multiple right hand sides B of shape `(...,n)`. But `scipy.linalg.lu_solve` only accepts a vector for b, not a matrix like `(m,n)` or `(k,m,n)`.
How can I wrap `lu_solve` to work for arguments of shape `(...,n)`? Numpy's `linalg.solve` would accept multiple `b`, but does not allow for separated LU factor and solve operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not mentioned in the documenation of [`lu_solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu_solve.html), but in fact `b` can contain multiple vectors.  If `A` has shape `(n, n)`, then `b` can have shape `(n, m)`.  For example,

```
In [44]: A                                                                                                           
Out[44]: 
array([[ 1.01,  0.02, -0.01],
       [ 0.02,  1.04, -0.02],
       [-0.01, -0.02,  1.01]])

In [45]: b                                                                                                           
Out[45]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [46]: lu = lu_factor(A)                                                                                           

In [47]: x = lu_solve(lu, b)                                                                                         

In [48]: x                                                                                                           
Out[48]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.98113208,  1.96226415,  2.94339623],
       [ 4.        ,  4.96226415,  5.9245283 ,  6.88679245],
       [ 8.        ,  9.01886792, 10.03773585, 11.05660377]])

In [49]: A.dot(x)                                                                                                    
Out[49]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.]])
```

Higher dimensional `b` must have shape `(n, ...)`.  Note that for shapes with more than two dimensions, testing the result with `A.dot(x)` will not work, because the shape of `x` will not be compatible with NumPy's matrix multiplication.  For example, here `B` has shape `(3, 2, 5)`:

```
In [40]: A                                                                      
Out[40]: 
array([[ 1.01,  0.02, -0.01],
       [ 0.02,  1.04, -0.02],
       [-0.01, -0.02,  1.01]])

In [41]: B = np.random.rand(3, 2, 5)                                            

In [42]: lu = lu_factor(A)                                                      

In [43]: x = lu_solve(lu, B)                                                    

In [44]: x.shape                                                                
Out[44]: (3, 2, 5)

In [45]: xx = np.moveaxis(x, 0, 1)                                              

In [46]: np.allclose(A.dot(xx), B)                                              
Out[46]: True
```

Comment: ```
import scipy.linalg, numpy as np
n = 10
A = np.random.rand(n,n)
LU_and_piv = scipy.linalg.lu_factor(A)
B = np.random.rand(2,5,n)
X = scipy.linalg.lu_solve(LU_and_piv, B)
```
throws ValueError: incompatible dimensions.
I'm using scipy 1.5.0

Comment: I see. How would I have to wrap scipy's lu_solve to make it more behave like numpy's solve, where B needs to be of shape (...,n) and the output is like (...,n)

Comment: In the wrapper, you could use something like `b = np.moveaxis(B, -1, 0)`, call `lu_solve` with `b` to get `x`, and then return `np.moveaxis(x, 0, -1)`.